# In OS X how do I add an environment variable which loads at startup time?

Tags: macos

In OS X how do I add an environment variable which loads at startup time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the file at `/etc/rc.common`

Add a line like the following:

```
export NEWVARIABLE="my new environment variable"
```